# What are these mushrooms growing in the mulch around my orange tree

Tags: identification, mulch, fungus, mushrooms

I have 2 or 3 types of mushrooms growing in the mulch around my orange tree near Houston, Texas (UDSA Zone 9a). What are they? The the last picture is actually 3 clustered, I haven't pulled it up yet because the bugs on it.

1:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

2:

[image]

[image]

3:

[image]

Comment: Not clear what you mean when you say 'not pulled it up yet because the bugs on it' can you clarify please. In the final picture, what is the green stem with what looks like some white fungal growth running up the right hand side on a dead part?

Comment: @Bamboo Was just saying I had'nt pull them up to show the underside to help with identification.The green thing is a a metal post use to support the tree.

Comment: Looks like triple ground mulch dyed with coal tar derivatives. If you can, it would be best to use some other mulch (not dyed), to be better for the environment.

Comment: Thank @J.Musser I will consider that. I'm new to homecoming so I appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All these appear to be growing out of soil which has a quite woody, fibrous mulch - which is where the mycelium have come from, and these are the fruiting bodies. I'm by no means even vaguely a mycologist, but the penultimate and last pictures may be Macrolepiota rhacodes, Shaggy Parasol - they start out one shape and end up another, and the white gills beneath become tinged with red as it ages. They may not be that at all, perhaps someone else can give a definite ID, so I wouldn't recommend you eat them without being 100% sure. You also mention something growing out of your lawn, but I see no lawn in the pics.